# JQuery load doesn't seem to process <script type=".." src="a.js">?

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I'm loading a page like this:

```
 function loadGUIComponents() {
// load contents into each accordion area
$("#listEntryDiv").load("listEntry/listEntryIndex.html");
$("#openEntryDiv").load("openEntry/openEntryIndex.html");
 };
```

In listEntryIndex.html, scripts like this can be called right:

```
<script>
alert("AHA!");
</script>
<h1>the world is helloed.</h1>
```

But if I try to externalize JS into a separate file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="listEntryIndex.js"></script>
<h1>the world is helloed.</h1>
```

The script will never be called. I really have googled a lot and am not getting the reason. People are asking why their javascripts are not called after being loaded, but mine is why only the  tag is not called after being loaded. Thanks!

Comment: What does `listEntryIndex.js` look like? You did remove the `<script>` tags there, correct?

Comment: you have a missing parenthesis `alert("AHA!");`

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have a <script> tag. It's like this: alert("AHA!"); And the missed parenthesis is a typing mistake.

Comment: @Darth: You should post that as an answer, I'll bet it's an issue with where the path is relative to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not jQuery `load` that's the problem, fundamentally that works: [Live example](http://jsbin.com/ukoha3) That example is using this code:

```
$("#target").load("http://jsbin.com/oqefe4");
```

To load this file:

```
<p>Test</p>
<script src='http://jsbin.com/ewexi4'></script>
```

...which references this one:

```
alert("Hello");
```

(I used full paths in the above, but [here's a version](http://jsbin.com/ukoha3/2) with relative paths; that works fine as well.)

This suggests that the actual problem lies elsewhere. You'll have to step through with a debugger to see what's going on. Fortunately, just about every browser [has one built in](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html) these days and there are free options for those that don't.

---

**Update**: You might have an issue with relative paths. When the text from your HTML file is loaded into the current document, paths within `script` (and `img`, etc.) tags in that HTML text will be resolved relative to the **current** document's location, not the location of the document you're loading. I'd look for 404 errors in the debugger, it's probably a path problem. This thought was triggered by a now-deleted comment on the question by @Darth___ (I think there was more to it) which questioned the paths... (**Edit**: It was DarthJDG; he's now [posted that as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880318/jquery-load-doesnt-seem-to-process-script-type-src-a-js/5880480#5880480). I bet it's the right one.)

So specifically, say your main document is at

```
http://example.com/foo/maindocument.html
```

Your `load` call is loading `listEntry/listEntryIndex.html` and `openEntry/openEntryIndex.html`, and those will be:

```
http://example.com/foo/listEntry/listEntryIndex.html
http://example.com/foo/openEntry/openEntryIndex.html
```

If the HTML *within* those has the script tag you listed, `listEntryIndex.js`, it will be resolved relative to `maindocument.html`, **not** relative to `listEntryIndex.html`, and thus:

```
http://example.com/foo/listEntryIndex.js
```

**not**

```
http://example.com/foo/listEntry/listEntryIndex.js
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. I think it might have sth to do with jquery-ui. I'm calling inside accordion component from jquery-ui. I tried your example, it works locally for me too. Could you please try loading the page as part of an accordion component from jquery-ui? I'm using jquery-ui-1.8.12

Comment: @Issac: I suspect not, I think it's the path thing that @DarthJDG first suggested in a comment on your question (and now in an answer).

Comment: AHA! Finally. After changing the path to listEntry/listEntryIndex.js it's finally WORKING!!!! GOOD JOB, GUYS! You are so helpful!   But this hints a problem with Rational Application Developer... It's mistakenly marking the rightful path to be invalid, and misguidingly gave me a warning... I'm openning a PMR to IBM Rational guys....

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure you reference your script in the src attribute correctly. From the above example, I'm assuming the current file structure:

```
./currentPage.html
./listEntry/listEntryIndex.html
./listEntry/listEntryIndex.js
./listEntryIndex.js <------------ //This file doesn't exist.
```

When you're loading content from a file at a different location, scripts included using relative paths might not be found. You should either copy the scripts or symlink them to make them locally accessible or use absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "listEntry/listEntryIndex.html",
  dataType: "script",
  success: function(data){
    $("#listEntryDiv").html(data);
  }
});

$.ajax({
  url: "openEntry/openEntryIndex.html",
  dataType: "script",
  success: function(data){
    $("#openEntryDiv").html(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: There you're telling jQuery that the *entire* response from the server is a script. Clearly it isn't, it's HTML with mixed-in script.

Comment: But it's not the way to evaluate javascript from the response ?

Comment: Not if the response is HTML, no. It would be if the response were JavaScript (rather than JavaScript *within* HTML, in a `script` element). jQuery's handling of HTML resources will automatically handle the script within the HTML, though, so something else is going on for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

From [.load() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML
>   property to parse the retrieved
>   document and insert it into the
>   current document. During this process,
>   browsers often filter elements from
>   the document such as , ,
>   or  elements. As a result, the
>   elements retrieved by .load() may not
>   be exactly the same as if the document
>   were retrieved directly by the
>   browser.

Have you maybe placed the `<script>` tag inside `<head>` and the browser strips it? Maybe play around with `<script>` tag placement.