# PHP JQuery Dialog & Datatables + losing layout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

So, I've a file (incident_view.php) with data from database. Everything works ok, and i'm using Datatables...

But, i've another page (status.php), and I'm using onclick to open it in a JQuery dialog "incident_view.php" page... Everything works great, the Jquery Dialog opens with correct data, but the table dont have the "Datatable's" layout  :(

My code in status.php:

```
    <body>
<?php
$plant="MNovo";
?>

    <div id="dialog" title="Plant incidents">
    </div>

    <script>        
    function incbox() {
            $( "#dialog" ).load('incident_view.php?idplant=<?php echo $plant ?>').dialog({ width:1000, maxHeight: 500  });
            $( "#opener" ).click(function() {$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );});
    }
    </script>
        <a href="javascript:incbox()"><?php echo utf8_encode("$plant");?></a>
</body>
```

What is wrong with it? :/

PS: Datatables inicialization in "incident_view.php"

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#inctables').dataTable( {

        "aLengthMenu": [[10,25, 50,  -1], [10,25, 50,  "All"]],
        "iDisplayLength": -1,
        "bScrollInfinite": true,
        "bScrollCollapse": true, //Scroll...
        "scrollY": "270px",
        "deferRender": true,
        "aaSorting": [],
        "order": [ [1,'desc'], [0,'asc'] ], //Order colmns by timestamp and equipment (inverter)
        } );
    } );
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other issues similar to this on stackoverflow - [JQuery load doesn't seem to process <script type=".." src="a.js">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880318/jquery-load-doesnt-seem-to-process-script-type-src-a-js) - you should check to make sure your relative paths are correct. It could be as simple as mistyped CSS.

Comment: If I creat a div in the same page (incident_view.php) :
<div id="dialog" title="Open Incidents to Plant"> datatables code...</div>
The Jquery Dialog displays correct all the data withou losing the datatable's layout... but, when I use onclick... IT's strange...